# java expression to logical operation

Tags: java, open-source

Is there a way in java we can convert an expression (xml or any other) to logical operations.

for example I have a property

prop01=Achivment:APPCom,done&&TODO:getforecast,!done;Achivement done

is there a way I convert it to java code like

```
    Map userData = getUserData();

    Map achivements = userData.get("achivements");
    Map TODOs = userData.get("TODOs");

    String achiv = achivements.get("APPCom");
    String todo = TODOs.get("getforecast");

    if(achiv == "done" && todo != "done")
        system.out.println("Achivement done"); // part after ; in expression
```

any third party available for this kind of task?

Comment: Only you know the semantics of your property.  If you shared more of them with us it may help us to make suggestions.  If your property has unique semantics, it is likely that no third party utility will be available to help you, but at least you may be able to find a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with any third party library directly. You may need to use some library like [Antlr](http://antlr.org/) to write a translator to translate from your expression to your Java code.